# pass value to catch errors occurring in the try

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

have a function in inside the try, and would like that when an error occurs during the process, a specific value is passed to the catch. 
How can I do this?

```
try
{
   value=x;
   function(....);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   messageError(....)
   function(x);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must declare a variable for the value before the try block, or pass this value Inside the exception (throw a custom exception containing the value you need for this error).

```
string value = null;
try
{
   value=x;
   function(....);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   messageError(....)
   if (value != null)
       function(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to declare null at the beginning.

Comment: @rysahara You're welcome. You have to do it because an exception could happen before you set the value. The compiler won't let you read a variable if it could be uninitialized. By giving a initial value, you ensure it's always set to something even if it's null.

Comment: Of course!!! the context thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its related to scope, you just add a variable out of try catch block (as above suggest).

```
public/protected string methodname()
{
  string strVariable = "";

  try
  {
    strVariable = "No Error";
  }
  catch(Exception EX)
  {
    strVariable = "Error";
  }

  return strVariable ;
}
```

Even if you want to access a variable globally in a page. You must declare at the intiation of class.

```
public class classname 
{
   public string strVariable = "";
}
```